# How to check if button has focus?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, button

I have a form that I am wanting to use the **ENTER** key to tab across the fields, but I am also wanting to submit the form when using the **ENTER** key when I have highlighted (by tabbing/entering to) a **send** button.

Is there any way in which I can tell if the enter button has been focussed?

I am thinking of something like:

```
<form (keydown.enter)="isSendFocussed($event)">
    <input #input1> <!-- input 1 -->
    <input #input2> <!-- input 2 -->
    <input #input3> <!-- input 3 -->
    <button #myButton (click)="sendForm()">Send</button>
</form>
```

I would then do something for the `isSendFocussed(event)` function such as:

```
@ViewChild('myButton') btn: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>

isSendFocussed(event) {
    // if (!button is focussed) {
    //     block default functionality and tab across
    // } else {
    //     send form
    // }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the focus and blur events like this:

```
<button
   (click)="onFavPopupClose()"
   (focus)="isBtnPopCloseFocused = true" 
   (blur)="isBtnPopCloseFocused = false">
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `(focus)` on your button element to check if it has been in its focused state.

**Template**

```
<button (focus)="isFocus($event)"></button>
```

**Component**

```
isFocus(evt): void {
  console.log('Button is focused', evt);
}
```